# How to get length in Javascript of an array of Form text fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, element

I have this HTML code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
a <input type="text" name="item[]" value="1" /> <br />
b <input type="text" name="item[]" value="1" /> <br />
c <input type="text" name="item[]" value="1" />
</form>
```

I can't seem to pro grammatically pull the length out of the text fields array , is there some obvious plain JavaScript way (no Jquery please) to do this? I tried

```
    <script language="javascript">
//Tried these combination
alert(document.form1.item.length);
alert(document.form1.item[].length);
alert(document.form1.elements['item'].length);
alert(document.form1.elements['item[]'].length);
</script>
```

Comment: what did you intend by *name="item[]"*?

Answer (score 2):

```
var inputCount = document.getElementById('form1').getElementsByTagName('input').length;
```

Note that, strictly speaking, your input elements do not constitute an array.  They're nodes in the DOM, so you have to find them as an array.

I know you said "no jQuery", but in this day and age it really perplexes me when people are resistant to using tools like that. They solve *lots* of problems that you'll otherwise end up solving yourself.

Comment: Thanks but I should mention this is for MOBILE IE which I don't think has getElementById support...

Comment: I would be shocked to learn that it has no getElementById() support. Now, it's probably broken like it is in regular IE (it returns elements based on the "name" attribute sometimes), but it would be pretty weird for it to be missing completely.  Then again, assuming Microsoft wouldn't do something weird like that is probably a bad idea.

Comment: :headslap: I don't think my teeth could stand the grinding if I were an MS Mobile developer - you have my admiration.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    <!-- 
    function Total() { 
    var i, ordertotal, discount, total; 
    ordertotal = 0; 
    nitems = 4 
    for (i=1; i<nitems+1; i++) { 
        eval("document.orderform.Item" + i + "Total.value = '';"); 
            if (document.forms[0]['Item'+i].checked==true){       
            eval("total=Number(document.orderform['ItemPrice[' + i + ']' + '[' + 0 + ']'].value);"); 
            eval("document.orderform.Item" + i + "Total.value=Currency(total)"); 
            eval("ordertotal = ordertotal + total;"); 
        } 
    } 
    document.orderform.OrderTotal.value = Currency(ordertotal); 
    discount = ordertotal * .5 
    document.orderform.Discount.value = Currency(discount); 
    document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = Currency(ordertotal + discount); 
    } 
    function Currency(anynum) { 
    anynum = "" + eval(anynum); 
    intnum = parseInt(anynum); 
    intnum = Math.abs(intnum); 
    intstr = ""+intnum; 
    if (intnum >= 1000) { 
    intlen = intstr.length 
    temp1=parseInt(""+(intnum/1000)) 
    temp2=intstr.substring(intlen-3,intlen) 
    intstr = temp1+","+temp2 
    } 
    if (intnum >= 1000000) { 
    intlen = intstr.length 
    temp1=parseInt(""+(intnum/1000000)) 
    temp2=intstr.substring(intlen-7,intlen) 
    intstr = temp1+","+temp2 
    } 
    decnum = Math.abs(parseFloat(anynum)-parseInt(anynum)); 
    decnum = decnum * 100; 
    decstr = "" + Math.abs(Math.round(decnum)) 
    if (decstr.length>2) {decstr=decstr.substring(0,2)} 
    while (decstr.length < 2) {decstr="0"+decstr} 
    retval = intstr + "." + decstr 
    if (anynum < 0) { 
    retval="("+retval+")" 
    } 
    return "$"+retval 
    } 
    //--> 
</script> 

<form name="orderform"> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="723">      

    <tr> 
        <th>Java script to calculate price with the double dimension arrays </th>
        <th>origional script modified by amarjit lehal :lehal2@hotmail.com</th>
        <th width="89" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F8FF" height="33">Item</th> 
        <th width="356" bgcolor="#F0F8FF" height="33">Description</th> 
        <th width="100" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F8FF" height="33">Price</th> 
        <th width="95" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F8FF" height="33">Total</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="89" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="Item1" value="1" onClick="Total();"></td> 
        <td width="356" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">Item1!</td> 
        <td width="100" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">$
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="ItemPrice[1][0]" size="9" value="5.50"></td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="Item1Total" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="89" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="Item2" onClick="Total();" value="1"></td> 
        <td width="356" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">Item2</td> 
        <td width="100" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">$
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="ItemPrice[2][0]" size="9" value="10.50"></td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="Item2Total" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="89" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="Item3" onClick="Total();" value="1"></td> 
        <td width="356" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">Item3</td> 
        <td width="100" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">$
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="ItemPrice[3][0]" size="9" value="20.50"></td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="Item3Total" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="89" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="Item4" onClick="Total();" value="1"></td> 
        <td width="356" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">Item4</td> 
        <td width="100" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">$
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="ItemPrice[4][0]" size="9" value="30.50"></td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="Item4Total" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="546" align="center" height="23" colspan="3" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <div align="right"> 
            <p>Order Total&nbsp; 
        </div> 
        </td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="OrderTotal" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="546" align="center" height="23" colspan="3" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <div align="right"> 
            <p>Discount&nbsp; 
        </div> 
        </td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="Discount" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td width="546" align="center" height="23" colspan="3" bgcolor="#F0F8FF"> 
        <div align="right"> 
            <p>Grand Total&nbsp; 
        </div> 
        </td> 
        <td width="95" align="center" height="23" bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="GrandTotal" size="10"></td> 
    </tr> 
</table> 
        <p><input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit"></p> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hi please add description for your answer it may help to understand the solution more clearly